# Fade between images in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have an `ImageView` in which I want to display two images, one after another. I want the transition between these two images to have a fade effect.
This is what I tried:

```
KeyFrame keyFrame1On = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(.2), new KeyValue(imageView.imageProperty(), image1, Interpolator.EASE_OUT));
KeyFrame keyFrame2On = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(.5), new KeyValue(imageView.imageProperty(), image2, Interpolator.EASE_OUT));
Timeline timelineOn = new Timeline(keyFrame1On, keyFrame2On);
timelineOn.setAutoReverse(false);
timelineOn.play();
```

But the transition between the images is solid, without fade.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what I had to do was just create another `ImageView`, then change the opacity of one of the image views.
Here is the FXML:

```
<AnchorPane fx:controller="br.atualy.importacaocte.controllers.DragAndDropController" maxHeight="-Infinity"
            maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="195.0" prefWidth="195.0"
            style="-fx-background-color: transparent"
            xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <ImageView fx:id="imageView" fitHeight="195.0" fitWidth="195.0"
               pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
        <Image url="@../img/drag_drop.png"/>
    </ImageView>
    <ImageView fx:id="imageViewHover" fitHeight="195.0" fitWidth="195.0"
               pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
        <Image url="@../img/drag_drop_hover.png"/>
    </ImageView>
</AnchorPane>
```

And here is the code:

```
KeyFrame kf1 = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0), new KeyValue(imageViewHover.opacityProperty(), 0));
        KeyFrame kf2 = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(.5), new KeyValue(imageViewHover.opacityProperty(), 1));
        KeyFrame kf3 = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1.5), new KeyValue(imageViewHover.opacityProperty(), 1));
        KeyFrame kf4 = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), new KeyValue(imageViewHover.opacityProperty(), 0));
        Timeline timelineOn = new Timeline(kf1, kf2, kf3, kf4);
        timelineOn.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
```

What it does is to create a "blink" effect between the two `ImageView`s.

Comment: You could also use [FadeTransition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/FadeTransition.html) for this, though what you have with Timeline is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 5):

The interpolator really isn't doing anything for you here (it just defines a mapping between the actual time and the parameter used to compute the values of the properties that are changing).

To implement a fade in/out you need to actually manipulate the`opacityProperty` of the `imageView` in the `Timeline`.

Try something like

```
KeyFrame keyFrame1On = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0), new KeyValue(imageView.imageProperty(), image1));
KeyFrame startFadeOut = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.2), new KeyValue(imageView.opacityProperty(), 1.0));
KeyFrame endFadeOut = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.5), new KeyValue(imageView.opacityProperty(), 0.0));
KeyFrame keyFrame2On = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.5), new KeyValue(imageView.imageProperty(), image2));
KeyFrame endFadeIn = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.8), new KeyValue(imageView.opacityProperty(), 1.0));
Timeline timelineOn = new Timeline(keyFrame1On, startFadeOut, endFadeOut, keyFrame2On, endFadeIn);
```

Comment: I didn't want to decrease the imageView opacity, just the second image's opacity over the first one. I think maybe i should use two imageviews, one above the other.

Comment: The code I provided fades the first image out, then the second one in. If you want both images present at the same time, then you need two `ImageView`s. Then just increase one's opacity and decrease the other simultaneously.

Comment: Hi @James_D I am having trouble understanding how KeyValue handles the ImageView.imageProperty(). I would think that it just inserts the Image into the ImageView but you set a time of .5 seconds on your second insert. Why?

Comment: @DanielH. That's correct; it will effectively call `imageView.setImage(...)` with the image specified in the `KeyValue` at the time specified in the `KeyFrame`. Not sure I understand the last part of your question. The idea is: make sure image1 is showing at the start, start fading out at 0.2 seconds, end fading out at 0.5 seconds, switch images at the same time point (0.5 seconds), fade back in, ending at 0.8 seconds.

Comment: @James_D I think you may have cleared my confusion. I was thinking that timeline would run each keyframe in sequence. but the way you describe it you have to rime your keyframes to start/finish at the correct point in time. You can not just say run a fadIn for .2 seconds and then insert the new image. The new image insert has to happen at .2

Comment: @DanielH. Think of movie editing software, where you can view each individual "frame" of the movie; each has a timepoint which is relative to the start of the movie. Same concept. At each "frame" the key value sets the specified property to the specified value; if it's an "interpolatable" value, then it's interpolated at each key frame, otherwise it's just set as specified.

Comment: @James_D ahhh! even better! now i fully understand. Thank you!